# Digital Bond Issuances on Ethereum

Tags: blockchain

I've been trying to better understand the mechanics of bond issuance on the blockchain such as [the one recently issued by EIB](https://www.eib.org/en/press/all/2021-141-european-investment-bank-eib-issues-its-first-ever-digital-bond-on-a-public-blockchain). Since this is a recent issuance I tried looking and asking for the investor roadshow slides, but was unable to find them. I read the prospectus. It was useful, but I'd like more.

There are a lot articles making reference to it but none of them care to explain the process. I also watched [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vAFvAWjKico) video on You Tube about a Santander issuance a few years ago, which was much more extensive.

Appreciate any other source of knowledge out there.

Answer (score 1):

The article that you linked does not include the contract address or the transaction(s) issuing the bond, so we don't know how exactly they did it.

However, they most likely deployed a smart contract (dApp) for that bond on Ethereum and used that contract to issue tokens to addresses of the investors. The tokens would represent fractional ownership of the bond.

It's funny that banks call themselves "innovative" when they do something that has been routinely done for the past 7 years (not for traditional bonds, but for many cryptoassets generally).

Edit: The contract [source code](https://etherscan.io/address/0x1Ff3D45E2c6c638A8d6BD1c81c99E6dB6D585EEb#code) has not been published, so we can't really know how it works. However, based on the transactions that I see, it seems to be an ERC20 token contract, probably customized. We can see what addresses were issued tokens (the bond) [here](https://etherscan.io/token/0x1ff3d45e2c6c638a8d6bd1c81c99e6db6d585eeb).

Comment: Here it is: https://etherscan.io/address/0x1Ff3D45E2c6c638A8d6BD1c81c99E6dB6D585EEb

Comment: See my edit above

Comment: Useful. Thanks. I wasn't sure if I was reading the information on etherscan correctly. Apparently, I was.

Comment: Would you mind inlcuding a link to the prospectus? I"m interested.

Comment: It's not available online. Probably because it was not available for US investors. I have a pdf version, but I can't upload a file here, can I?

Comment: No we can't and there is no private message on stackexchange... It doesn't matter, it was just out of curiosity.